# Where is the list of countries eligible for the visa-exempt 90/180 Schengen rule?

Tags: schengen

Somewhere in this stack, I recently read an answer that had a link to this list.  (I assume—I didn't actually follow the link.)

But today, I can't find that answer.  I am wondering where I would find an official version of that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the list of countries eligible for the visa-exempt 90/180 Schengen rule?

COUNCIL REGULATION (EC) No 539/2001 of 15 March 2001

> listing the third countries whose nationals must be in possession of visas when crossing the external borders and those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement

> [Article 1](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02001R0539-20170611#tocId4)
>
> 1. Nationals of third countries on the list in [Annex I](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02001R0539-20170611#tocId16) shall be required to be in possession of a visa when crossing the external borders of the Member States.
>    ...
>    Nationals of third countries on the list in [Annex II](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02001R0539-20170611#tocId17) shall be exempt from the requirement set out in paragraph 1 for stays of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period.
>    The following shall also be exempt from the visa requirement:
>    ...

Should the visa requirement of one country be removed, then that country will be removed from **Annex I** and added to **Annex II**.

Comment: Those links are to "text [that] is meant purely as a documentation tool and has no legal effect."  But that text links to the official list, so I'll check this answer.  Interesting that annex two of the "documentation tool" ends with six that are not at the end of the "official text."  These are: British nationals, British overseas territories citizens, British overseas citizens, British protected persons, British subjects, Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

Information about who must apply for a Schengen visa is published on the EU Migration and Home Affairs website https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/index_en

Short stay and airport transit visa requirements are summarised on https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/who-must-apply-schengen-visa_en and a link is given to the Lists of third countries whose nationals must be in possession of a visa when crossing the external borders and of those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement
https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-05/list%20of%20countries%20whose%20citizens%20must%20have%20a%20visa%20when%20crossing%20the%20external%20borders%20and%20those%20whose%20nationals%20are%20exempt%20from%20that%20requirement_en.pdf